# How to search for a resource in resource chain in MFC?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a dialog template in an extension DLL. I need to create that dialog from another module(exe). But before creating that dialog, i need to know the dialog size. So i tried to get the dialog size from the dialog template. Here is my code -

```
CSize CEMCNewPropertyPage::CalcDialogSize()
{
    CSize size(0, 0);
    HRSRC hRsrc = FindResource(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),MAKEINTRESOURCE(m_nResourceID), RT_DIALOG); 

    if(hRsrc == NULL)
        return size;

    HGLOBAL hTemplate = ::LoadResource(AfxGetResourceHandle(), hRsrc); 

    if(hTemplate == NULL)
        return NULL;

    DLGTEMPLATE* pTemplate = (DLGTEMPLATE*)::LockResource(hTemplate); 

    if(pTemplate == NULL)
        return NULL;

    size.cx = pTemplate->cx;
    size.cy = pTemplate->cy;
    ::UnlockResource(hTemplate); 

    return size; 
}
```

Here, `FindResource` is returning `NULL`. But the dialog template is in the resource file of that extension DLL.  So i am assuming that,  `FindResource` is not searching the whole resource chain. So, is there any way to force to carry out the search in the whole resource chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a dialog template in an extension DLL

You need to save the current resource handle ([AfxGetResourceHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaewt3xs.aspx)) and set it to the **extension dll** using [AfxSetResourceHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ws31ff.aspx).  When you are done working with the template, you need to restore the resource handle back to its previous setting.  As you suspected, your current code is actually looking in the exe only.

Comment: So, first i need to search with the resourceID to get the resource handle of the extensionDLL. I dont understand how to do it!

Comment: FindResource uses the current resource handle when performing the search.  That typically defaults to the application (.exe).  In order to search  in other executables (ie. dlls), you need to set the resource handle to point to the dll using the commands I've given you.  Please refer to the links above.